# Centering a div with a float property

Tags: css

this may looks like the usual how to center a float question but the reason i need to center a float div is because other div container is also having a float property. I have set an height auto to determine the height depend on the object inside the wrapper div, within the wrapper div there is 2 float div to make it side by side. However if i did not specify a float on the wrapper the wrapper div would only show 1 staight line(not wrapping anything)

```
div.wrapper{
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 30px;
float: left;
border:1px solid gray;
}

div.leftcontainer{
width: 200px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
border:1px solid gray;
float: left;
}

div.right container{
width: 750px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
border:1px solid gray;
float: right;
}
```

And this is my html code

```
<div class ="wrapper">
 <div class ="leftcontainer">
   some options
 </div>
 <div class = "rightcontainer">
   some options
 </div>
 <div class = "rightcontainer">
   some options
 </div>

</div>
```

So how do i make my wrapper div centered Without removing the float or other way to do achieve this? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by :center  a float div ?, if you want to center a div, remove the float and put margin:0 auto

Answer (score 0):

With all of the contents of `.wrapper` floating, you need to clear them.

Remove the float on `.wrapper` and add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` before you close the `.wrapper` div.

You should then be able to add:

```
div.wrapper { 
    /* ... */
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

And your wrapper will be centered.

Comment: Hm yes it indeed would be centered. But however if i have floating div inside the wrapper the wrapper would not wrap around them instead behaving as wrapping nothing.

Comment: As long as the interior divs are `position:relative;` and you have a div that clears both (`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`) it will wrap all of its contents.